# Huawei Health Kit API not showing protein value

Tags: huawei-mobile-services, healthkit

I hope you can help me...the thing is that I'm getting all the samplepoints from the Health kit API and it's working fine except for the protein value it shows always 0, I've checked the Huawei Health App and over there is showing correctly a value from protein, the device used is a Matepad T8, this is the short answer from the endpoint

```
{"samplePoints":{
"com.huawei.instantaneus.body_weight":{"startTime":1640210232971000000,"endTime":1640210232971000000:, "dataTypeName":"com.huawei.instantaneous.body_weight","originalDataCollectorId":"raw:com.huawei.instantaneous.body_weight:com.huawei.health:HUAWEI:HUAWEI Body Fat Scale:5C:CA:D3:08:07:C2:168969165","value":[{"fieldName":"body_weight","floatValue":81.80000305175781},{"fieldName":protein_rate"},{....}]}}}
```

This is the Health App if you see there is protein data
[image]

and in the app Im developing shows 0 because the endpoint is giving 0 value, this is from the Matepad T8

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

May i confirm what is your countries/regions? The protein rate is calculated only when the following three fields are met when the REST interface queries the body weight. [Docs link](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides/weight-0000001131423772?ha_source=hms1).

[image]

so to locate this issue, please provide the complete data returned by the REST API.

---

Could you pls check whether the conditions are met according to the [document](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides/overview-restful-api-0000001177993395#section179971037122318)?

[image]

Also please check whether the data source is from Huawei's body fat scale. According to [this docs](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides/weight-0000001131423772), protein and other data are measured by body fat.

And it would be great if you could provide us with a picture of the weight parameter data displayed in your HealthApp for us to locate the problem.

Comment: I added more info and screenshots

Comment: hi@Angel Pat Martin, i updated my answer, kindly refer that.